# Unable to access json object property and value is displayed undefined in rails view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

I've almost viewed similar kind of questions but my problem has not solved yet.

I've following codes.

**Controller**

```
def create
    @task_list = TaskList.new(task_list_params)

    if @task_list.save
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render json: @task_list}
        end
    else
        return
    end
end
```

**Ajax Script**

```
$(document).on('click','.add', function(){

  count = 0;
  user_id = $('#user_id').val();
  var name = $('.new-list').val();
  var current = $(this);
  if(name){
    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: action,
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: { 
        task_list: {
          name: name, 
          user_id: user_id 
        }
      }
    }).success(function(response){
      var data = JSON.stringify(response);
      alert(data.id);
      $(current).parent().parent().parent().before(
        '<div class="col-md-12">'+
          '<a href="task_list/" class="btn btn-xs list ">'+name+'</a>'+
        '</div>'
        );
      $(current).parent().parent().parent().remove();
      $('.add-list').show();
    });
  }else{
    alert('please add title');
  }
```

});

I just want to take id of the record just saved to the database through ajax post request. Here, in success function it just alerts undefined and I don't know what's going wrong.

This is sample response.

[image]

Comment: Directly use `response.id`, You don't need `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.success(function(response){
      alert(response.id);
```

Remove JSON.stringify from your success function. Response is already in JSON format you can directly get the value from it.

JSON.stringfy converts javascript object into string.

### Explanation

Your response is already in JSON format and you have used dataType: "JSON" in your AJAX call. Which will make it possible to transfer JSON data between server and client. 
When your response is already in JSON format you can use its property without parsing it. I.e response.id

If you have not used dataType: "JSON" and you are passing json encoded response from your controller to view file you have to first decode the response to get its values.

```
var d = $.parseJSON(response);
alert(d.id);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it works perfectly can you explain in detail about whats the wrong, I'm new to front end and rails.

Comment: Please check explanation in my answer. Hope its clear to you now. Also please mark answer approved if it has solved your issue. :) Thanks @SagarGautam

Comment: Thanks for your time and kind information, I'll accept this answer